# convert multiple list to multiple dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe

```
list = [list1, list2, list3]
df1=pd.DataFrame(list1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(list2)
df3=pd.DataFrame(list3)
```

I have big dataframe, and I'm try to automate. How can I make like this in for loop but without manually typing variables and names?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
list1 = [1,3,4,5]
list2 = [7,8,9,0]
list3 = [5,6,7,8]

d2 = {}
list_df =[]  # this will contains list of DataFrames
lists = [list1, list2, list3] 

for ind,l in enumerate(lists):
  if ind not in d2:
    d2[f'list_{ind}']=l
    list_df.append(pd.DataFrame(d2))

list_df[0]  # later you can retrieve the dataframes using index
```

Comment: Its showing error: ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: try to run all cells, you might be passing empty d2

Comment: i have edited the solution now try this

Comment: Its working fine. Thank you. But I dont want to mention variable list1 = [1,3,4,5] like this, because I'm try to do automatically.

I already have the combined list, I want to assign variable for each element in the list

Comment: This is just an example, you can go ahead with your combined list and try to change the source code as per your requirement.  try some other name in place of list `d2[f'list_{ind}']=l`